# std::map insert thread safe in c++11?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, dictionary

I have very simple code in which multiple threads are trying to insert data in std::map and as per my understanding this should led to program crash because this is data race

```
std::map<long long,long long> k1map;
void Ktask()
{
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        long long random_variable = (std::rand())%1000;
        std::cout << "Thread ID -> " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " with looping index " << i << std::endl;
        k1map.insert(std::make_pair(random_variable, random_variable));
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::srand((int)std::time(0)); // use current time as seed for random generator
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
           std::thread t(Ktask);
           std::cout << "Thread created " << t.get_id() << std::endl;
           t.detach();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However i ran it multiple time and there is no application crash and if run same code with pthread and c++03 application is crashing so I am wondering is there some change in c++11 that make map insert thread safe ?

Comment: If your code is not *provably* thread-safe, then you should not assume that it is. You should not assume that anything with regard to threading is fine just because the program didn't crash.

Comment: Yes i understand that but issue is similar code that we are using in production environment is crashing and the code is crashing where map internal tree is rebalancing so just want to know is there any change in c++11 for map insert thread safety because there we are using c++03 with phreads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `std::map::insert` is not thread-safe.

There are many reasons why your example may not crash. Your threads may be running in a serial fashion due to the system scheduler, or because they finish very quickly (1000 iterations isn't that much). Your map will fill up quickly (only having 1000 nodes) and therefore later insertions won't actually modify the structure and reduce possibility of crashes. Or perhaps the implementation you're using IS thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

For most standard library types, the only thread safety guarantee you get is that it is safe to use separate object instances in separate threads. That's it.

And `std::map` is not one of the exceptions to that rule. An implementation might offer you more of a guarantee, or you could just be getting lucky.

And when it comes to fixing threading bugs, there's only one kind of luck.